# AVR ATmega32 program execution stops on function call

Tags: microcontroller, avr

I'm doing an embedded electronics project, and my code stops executing at function calls whose respective functions have several instructions. My MCU is an Atmel ATmega32L-8PU. It runs at 8 MHz, which is defined in Symbols under Project Properties in Atmel Studio 7. I am using an AVRISP MKII debugger and programmer.

This code works (such that the status LED is blinking):

```
void printFeeder()  {
    if (TCNT1 > 15625)  {
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    DDRD |= 0xFF;
    while (1) 
    {
        PORTD ^= 0x08; // Status LED.
        printFeeder();
        _delay_ms(1000);
    }
}
```

This code will turn the status LED on once, but it will not blink, leading me to believe the code gets stuck on the function call. Not only that, but it will get stuck on an sei() call as well.

```
void printFeeder()  {
    if (TCNT1 > 15625)  {
        TCNT1 = 0;
        PORTD ^= 0x04;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    DDRD |= 0xFF;
    while (1) 
    {
        PORTD ^= 0x08; // Status LED.
        printFeeder();
        _delay_ms(1000);
    }
}
```

Notice the only differences between these blocks of code are the contents of the printFeeder() functions. The issue is not the with the Timer,  Counter, or Interrupt setups, because I've tested other function calls that had simple variable reassignments, and if the contents of these functions were longer than two or three lines, program execution would stop.

Comment: Hi, does it reach the point where it toggles the other port D pin?

Comment: @jramsay42 No, unfortunately not. I tried commenting the TCNT1 = 0 statement, to no avail. I believe that the other Port D bin will toggle if it is the only statement in the function. I have reason to believe my MCU is somehow corrupted, as my code ran fine on another MCU of the exact same type.

Comment: I know I've had some odd issues in the past with AVRs involving the fuses etc, trying to find some of the old info I had on this now

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the AVR in question with another of the same type solved the problems I was having. I do believe the AVR in question was defective, because the fuse values between all of my chips were the same, and the AVR in question was not mishandled by me.

Comment: That is quite unlikely

Comment: @Chris Stratton Your incomplete answer leaves much to contemplate. The SRAM in the chip was malfunctioning, since the stack pointer was never returning from the calling function. I tested this with a backup chip with identical fuses.

Comment: Again, that is extremely unlikely.  You likely have an unrecognized program error influenced by seemingly unrelated conditions (quite common) or are operating the board out of specification.

Comment: The chip was faulty. If it has a program error then it was with the chip's own microcode or SRAM configuration. The code listed above is the cut-down verison. It took a few hours of debugging deduce this. There is no question in that. Replacing the faulty chip with an identical one shipped in the same container resolved all of my issues.

Comment: You can say that all you want, but it won't change the **fact** that it is orders of magnitude more likely that you have an unknown issue that causes failures in some cases and not others.  Essentially you are *misusing* the chip, but getting away with it in some circumstances.  You need to figure out what the *actual* design defect in your project is, as you can't rely on what you are getting away with now consistently working.

Comment: And how exactly would I be misusing the IC given the information I provided? If you cannot answer then you are levelling at me false accusations that I refuse to heed. So far you have provided me no concrete suggestions, only faulty inductions purely based off of your conjectures. Even the simplest project configuration and fuse setup yield unexpected results on the one chip, out of the three that correctly produced the right output. Any fact that you claim to provide by no means is a step in the right direction, only a means to dilapidate a project that successfully concluded years ago.